# boundary value problem. Confusion with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Find all the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for the following Boundary value problem:

$y''+ \lambda y = 0$ ; $y(- \pi)=y(\pi)$, $y'(-\pi)=y(\pi)$

[image]I'm just confused at the $\lambda = 0$ case, how was $y(x)=1$ obtained from $y(x)=c_1$. I feel like I am missing something very obvious. Could someone clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the necessary information so that your question is self contained (i.e. doesn't require visiting an external site).

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BC read:

$$y(-\pi) =y(\pi)$$
and
$$y'(-\pi) = y(\pi)$$

Plugging in the expression for $y$ in the first gives:
$c_1 -c_2\pi=c_1 + c_2\pi \Rightarrow c_2 = -c_2 \Rightarrow  c_2 =0$

The second results in:
$c_2 = c_1 +c_2\pi \Rightarrow c_1 = 0$

Thus, are you sure your BC are right? If the second one reads:
$$y'(-\pi) = y'(\pi)$$ you'd get $y(x) = 1$ as an eigenfunction. (note, $y(x) = c_1$ is eigenfunction is equivalent with $y(x) =1$ is an eigenfunction.)

Comment: Where is that $y(x)=1$ coming from though? That's the part I can't figure out. I feel like it's something very stupid and obvious I am missing.

Comment: If the second BC is of the form I stated, we don't have an equation for $c_1$. This means $c_1$ can be any number one wishes and $y$ would still be a solution.

Comment: Yeah it's the form you picked. I see. So the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: Remember from linear algebra: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ thus $Av = \lambda v$ then for any nonzero constant $c_1$ we have: $A(c_1 v) = c_1 Av = c_1 \lambda v = \lambda (c_1 v)$ thus $(c_1 v)$ is an eigenvector as well. We do have an extra degree of freedom in the choice of $c_1$ but, we might as well pick it to be $1$.